# What's wrong with this javascript ajax code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [$ not defined in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421910/not-defined-in-javascript)

Firebug is telling me:

> `ReferenceError: $ is not defined [Break On This Error]`
>
> > `$.ajax({`

but I'm not sure why, or how would I correct this?

This is supposed to write the data from the facebook auth to a url or something so that I can retrieve it later with java.

```
 <script>
      function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // connected
                    console.log((response));
                    console.log((response.session));
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "fbReceiver.html", 
                        data: response,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function() {}
                    });
                
                } else {
                    // cancelled
                }
            });
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: You sure jQuery is properly loaded?

Comment: is the jquery.js build in? load this ajax at $(document).ready(function() {...}); maybe?

Comment: Javascript != jQuery. You forgot to include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the jQuery file is loaded *above* the code you have here.

```
<script src="jQuery file here"></script>

<script> your code here <script>
```

You can get the URL of the jQuery file here: http://jquery.com/

Comment: Thank you :), first timer with jQuery here and I was sure missing that